# Getting non-exhaustive pattern exception on method

Tags: haskell, accumulator, non-exhaustive-patterns

I keep getting `non-exhaustive pattern` exception for the following method:

```
 groups::[Int]->[[Int]]
 groups ls=go ls [] [] where

        go [] small big=small:big
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) big | x==y = go xs (x:y:ys) big
                             | otherwise = go xs [] ((y:ys):big)
```

What i want to do is : given an array `[1,2,3,3,4,4,4,1]` i want to split it in list of  consecutive duplicates: `[[1],[2],[3,3],[4,4,4],[1]]`.

I am using `2` accumulators , one for the current forming list and the other for the big one.

I can not use `wild-card` neither for the `big` list neither for the `small` one , since the only situation that is unusual is the empty input list.

Comment: you haven't accounted for the case where the first argument to `go` is non-empty but the second is empty

Comment: also you don't have to define this function yourself, [group](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) from Data.List does it already

Comment: It was for learning purposes

Answer (score 1):

You haven't accounted for something like `go (x:xs) [] big`; the only case that allows the second argument to be an empty list also requires the first argument to be an empty list as well.

```
    go [] small big=small:big
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) big | x==y = go xs (x:y:ys) big
                         | otherwise = go xs [] ((y:ys):big)
    go (x:xs) [] big = ???
```